# No visual update on state change when using map

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code that renders in my class component.

When I change the state of toDisplay to another list, the log in the console shows the correct list of datasets, however, the display doesn't change.

```js
<div className=" flex flex-col justify-center">
          <div className="w-full max-w-7xl flex flex-row flex-wrap place-self-center place-content-center">
            {this.state.toDisplay.length > 0 ? (
              console.log(this.state.toDisplay),
              this.state.toDisplay.map((dataset, i) => (
                <div className="max-w-2xl m-3 text-white">
                  <DatasetInfo dataset={dataset} key={i} app={this.props.app} />
                </div>
              ))
            ) : (
              <div
                class="bg-blue-100 border-t border-b border-blue-500 text-blue-700 px-4 py-3 mt-10"
                role="alert"
              >
                <p class="font-bold">No Datasets</p>
                <p class="text-sm">
                  It appears there are no datasets to show in this category
                </p>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
```

I update the toDisplay state as follows:

```
  changeTab(event) {
    this.setState({ selectedTab: event.target.id });
    if (event.target.id === "1") {
      this.setState({ toDisplay: this.state.forSaleList });
    } else if (event.target.id === "2") {
      this.setState({ toDisplay: this.state.hiddenList });
    } else if (event.target.id === "3") {
      this.setState({ toDisplay: this.state.purchasedList });
    } 
  }
```

This function is the on-click method for some tabs on the site

Comment: you aren't doing anything with the output of `this.state.toDisplay.map()`. `Array#map()` returns a new array, which you aren't capturing or using.

Comment: @2pichar It's rendering a new DatasetInfo component for each item in the array

Comment: How do yo update the array toDisplay? You could edit the question to show how it is done

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are updating the array wrongly: if you don't set it in your state with a new copy of the array, the console log will display the updated array, but it will not trigger a visual update of your component, because the state didn't really updated, since it is still the same array (with maybe some new items, but it doens't matter).

So in order to trigger an update, you should set a copy of the array in your local state:

```
// Modify the array as you wish
// And then, set it in the local state
setState({toDisplay: [...this.state.toDisplay]})
```

Comment: I have a handler function when a new tab is clicked to update the toDisplay state as follows: `this.setState({ toDisplay: this.state.purchasedList });` and the list it's assigned depends on the tab. I tried doing [...this.state.purchasedList] but still no update. I find it strange that the console logs the correct array but there is no display update

Comment: Could you show a bit more code about how you set the state with this new array please ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the display to update by changing the key from i to the id of the dataset as below:

```
this.state.toDisplay.map((dataset, i) => (
                <div className="max-w-2xl m-3 text-white">
                  <DatasetInfo dataset={dataset} key={dataset.id} app={this.props.app} />
                </div>
              ))
```